# Error System.ArgumentException: "Keyword not supported: "charset"."

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

im trying to insert some data into my database by using dataGridView and filling it cells but i get the following error `System.ArgumentException: "Keyword not supported: "charset"."`

Here is my code:

```
        public string connect = "Server=localhost;Database=hardlight;Uid=root;pwd=platon6993;charset=utf8";

string StrQuery;
                
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            comm.Connection = conn;
                            conn.Open();
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO rabota VALUES ("
                                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value + ", "
                                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["name"].Value + ", "
                                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dadada"].Value + ");";
                                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

what can i do? Please help

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Your connection string is wrong, where did you get it from? Also, you have **dangerous** SQL injection going on here, you *must* parameterize your statement. And it's advisable to specify the columns you are inserting into

Comment: There is also no need to generate separate insert for each row in datagridview, you can do it in single insert. 
Example like this: 
insert into rabota values (1,’name1’,1), (2,’name2’,2), (3, ‘name3’,3)

Comment: I dont get it why my connection string is wrong, it connects and i can read the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove charset, your connection string should be like this

```
  public string connect = "Server=localhost;Database=hardlight;Uid=root;Pwd=platon6993;";
```

you query string should contain ' ' for string values

```
 StrQuery = $"INSERT INTO rabota VALUES ( {dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value},'{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["name"].Value}', '{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dadada"].Value}')";
```

Comment: I guess this kinda works! But now i get an Error `Data truncated for column 'dadada' at row 1`, for some reason

Comment: @xto sorry, It was a typo, I fixed my code

Comment: It cant connect with `Integrated Security=False` and only connects when i remove this from script string. What did you mean by "you query string should contain ' ' for string values" i dont get it to be honest

Comment: @xto inside of the script should be for example "  where  id=5 or  name='John'  ", not " where name=John  ". the same in your query varchar params should be inside ' '

Comment: I think it worked but it gives me an error now `MySqlConnector.MySqlException:` and complains about the first string in my table which i filled manualy while creating the database